# separate physic node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, physics

I am a bit confused and can't clearly picture what I have to do next.

I have a node.js server that runs p2.js physics on it, which is needed for my multiplayer game. In this multiplayer game, each game consists of two players. So, for every two players, the server creates a new socket.io room and lets the user join them.

My goal is to achieve that the physics which runs on the server should be every time instantiated and work independently from each other when a new room is generated.

I thought about creating a new node instance but I think this is inefficient for more than 10 games.

Which possibilities do I have then to generate a new physic instance on my node server for every room generated?

Comment: Hey Lyian...did  you manage to get a good performance with nodejs and p2? I'm trying something very similar as I don't have the time to learn C.